# Custom post type - get_day_link()

Tags: custom-post-types, php, archives

How can I get the archive links for a custom post type? [get_day_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_day_link) doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head, `get_day_link()` does not work for custom post types. This might work in 3.1 as you can add archives to your custom post types.

Comment: tweak this: http://wordpress.org/extend/ideas/topic/improved-wp_get_archives ?